short exact sequence $ 0 \to \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G} \to 0 $ of sheaves s.t $\mathcal{F}(X) \to \mathcal{G}(X)$ is not surjective?
Consider the topological space whose underlying set is $X = \{0, 1, 2\}$ and with open sets
$$
\emptyset, \ U_0 = \{0\}, \ U_1 = \{0, 1\}, \ U_2 = \{0, 2\}, \ X = \{0, 1, 2\}.
$$
Consider a presheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of abelian groups on $X$:
$$
A_X = \mathcal{F}(X), \quad A_i = \mathcal{F}(U_i) \ \text{(for} \ i = 0,1,2), \quad A_\emptyset = \mathcal{F}(\emptyset).
$$
The homomorphisms in part of the diagram below concerning the $A_i$'s are the restriction maps of $\mathcal{F}$. For simplicity of notation, we write $\rho_i$ instead of $\rho_{X, U_i}$ and $r_i$ instead of $\rho_{U_i, U_0}$.
Suppose that the following conditions are satisfied:

$A_\emptyset = 0$,
the map $(\rho_1, \rho_2): A_X \to A_1 \times A_2$ induces an isomorphism
$$ A_X \xrightarrow{\,\sim\,} A_1 \times_{A_0} A_2 := \{(a_1, a_2) \in A_1 \times A_2 \ | \ r_1(a_1) = r_2(a_2)\}. $$

Then $\mathcal{F}$ is a sheaf.
What is an explicit example of a short exact sequence
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{E} \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G} \to 0 $$
of sheaves on $X$ such that the induced map $\varphi_X: \mathcal{F}(X) \to \mathcal{G}(X)$ is not surjective?
Note that a homomorphism $\varphi: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$ of (pre)sheaves of abelian groups is given by a commutative diagram below where $\mathcal{G}$ is given by the groups $B_i$.


Just to clarify: you want an example (of an epimorphism of sheaves which is not surjective on sections) for this specific 3-point topological space, not for any space?

@MartinBrandenburg Yes, for this specific example, assuming epimorphism of sheaves is the same as short exact sequence of sheaves?

We have $\mathcal{E} = \ker(\varphi)$, so you are only looking for an epimorphism of sheaves which is not surjective on global sections. The condition that the morphism $\varphi$ is an epimorphism of sheaves means that each $A_i \to B_i$ is an epimorphism (since $A_i$ is the stalk of $i \in X$). We want an example where this does not imply that $\varphi(X) : A_1 \times_{A_0} A_2 \to B_1 \times_{B_0} B_2$ is an epimorphism. That is easy. For any non-trivial abelian group $C$, take $A_i = C$ with identity restrictions, and $B_1 = C$, $B_2 = C$, $B_0 = 0$. Then $\varphi(X)$ is just the diagonal $C \to C \times C$.

What would the short exact sequence be?

See my edit. It is $0 \to \ker(\varphi) \xrightarrow{\subseteq} \mathcal{F} \xrightarrow{\varphi} \mathcal{G} \to 0$.

I don't quite see  $\varphi (X)$ became the diagonal (why is $C\times_{A_0}C=C$ and the other one with $B_0$), and why this means that it is not surjective. what does the subindex in $\times_{A_0}$  mean?

Just compute it. It is the fiber product, the same notation as in your question.

it looks like a cartesian product , I don't see what information the $A_0$ in the $\times_{A_0}$ gives

You haven't read your own question which has the definition of $A_1 \times_{A_0} A_2$? And please google "fiber product" and "sheaf condition".
